# Запрет открытия сайта более чем в одной вкладке

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет.

**Задача**: при открытии пользователем сайта во второй вкладке браузера, в первой вкладке должно появиться сообщение о том, что открыта новая вкладка.

Есть ли возможность реализовать этот функционал с максимальной кроссбраузерностью?

Comment: Как вариант - при открытии страницы делать отметку в cookie или localStorage, а при закрытии страницы очищать его. + проверка этой отметки с определенным интервалом

Comment: Если что, любой возможный способ реализации ограничения пользователь сможет обойти

Comment: А вариант того, что человек может открыть в разных браузерах (как на одном, так и на разных устройствах) - не рассматриваете?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "Есть ли возможность реализовать этот функционал с максимальной кроссбраузерностью?"

Comment: А зачем это нужно? Не костылите ли?

Comment: @larrymacbarry например, чтобы не списать много денег, ну или внутренней валюты со счёта. Человек накидал в корзину товар, отвлёкся, пошел вконтактик, потом открыл еще одну вкладку, кинул тот же товарчик и жмакнул оплатить и не читая жмакнул на окно подтверждения. Всё.

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich что значит "с кроссбраузерностью" в случае когда юзер открыл браузеры на разных устройствах? А то я не понимаю причем тут кроссбраузерность если открыт сайт в хроме на ПК, в хроме на планшете, хроме на смартфоне  и хроме еще где-либо еще.

Comment: Кроссбраузерность -- имеется в виду поддержка на разных браузерах (в т.ч. Safari, Opera)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Открывать сайт в нескольких браузерах можно, но не более одного раза в каждом. У каждых браузеров куки то в разных местах хранятся...

Comment: @SviatoslavZaytsev ну так есть способы запрета на сервере, а не только на клиенте. Однако если ничего критичного нет на сайте, то и мухлежи с вкладками не имеет смысла. В противном случае нужно делать не только опираясь на js.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Разве за это не отвечают сессии куки в норм магазинах? Обычно товары добавляются на бэке, даже если с помощью ajax-корзины. Так человек хоть закроет страницу, товар будет в корзинке.

Comment: @larrymacbarry я разве что-то писал про реализацию? суть в одном - ограничение одной вкладкой минимизирует шанс глупости юзера. А примеров может быть достаточно много. Например не позволять запускать несколько вкладок с онлайн казино одновременно, бгг)) Хотя только клиентом ограничиваться в таком случае крайне глупо. В общем, вы просто не сталкивались с такими случаями, когда это необходимо

Comment: @larrymacbarry объясните зачем предусматривать то, что юзеру никак не нужно? если юзер выбирает билет и открывает вторую вкладку с тем же мероприятием, то ему нужно потакать синхронизацией между собой состояний нескольких интерфейсов одного и того же?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всем спасибо за наводки и примеры.
Вот окончательное решение:

```
    window.session = revoke(5);
    localStorage.setItem("session", window.session);
    var onStorage = function (e) {
        if (e.key === 'session' && e.newValue !== window.session)
            localStorage.setItem("multitab", window.session);
        if (e.key === "multitab" && e.newValue && e.newValue !== window.session) {
            window.removeEventListener("storage", onStorage);
            localStorage.setItem("session", localStorage.getItem("multitab"));
            localStorage.removeItem("multitab");
            alert("Новая вкладка");
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener('storage', onStorage);
```

P.S. revoke(5) -- функция, которая генерирует ключ, с длиной 5.

Answer (score 4):

ниже небольшая реализация. alert будет вызываться при каждом открытии нового табика.

```js
var currentTabId = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000);
localStorage.setItem('currentTabId', currentTabId);

setInterval(function () {
    var newTabId = localStorage.getItem('currentTabId');
    if (currentTabId != newTabId) {
        alert('New tab');
        currentTabId = newTabId;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Сейчас работаю над реализацией без setInterval, но направление правильное)